# Hamburger Menu Navigation (Small Issue)

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

I'm having a small error with my hamburger menu. It functions the way it should and opens and closes when I click on the hamburger icon, the issue is that when it is closed, I can see a very small part of the top link that would be at the top of the navigation menu. The small line you can see in the image is a border 1px to the right of the nav links. The titles of the nav links are floated to the left.

[image: This is where you can see the top of the button. I can even click on this button.]

This is what it looks like when opened:

[image: Opened Hamburger Menu]

```css
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  START OF NAVIGATION MENU 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

.header a {
  color: #000;
} /* Sets colour of the links within the navigation bar */

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
} /* Sets colour, adds box shadow underneath nav, makes nav static and sets positioning */

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0px;
} /* Sets positioning and background colour of the nav links */

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #b3b2b2;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
} /* Sets positioning, adds border line, and removes any text decoration  */


.header li a {
    background-image: linear-gradient(currentColor, currentColor);
    background-position: 0% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 0% 2px;
    transition: background-size .3s;
} /* Sets positioning, adds border line, and removes any text decoration  */

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover,
.header li a:focus {
  background-color: #f8f7f7;
  background-size: 100% 2px;
} /* Sets background colour of nav links when you hover over them */

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left:15%;
} /* Sets positioning, removes any text decoration, sets font-size */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .25s ease-out;
  margin-right: 15%;
} /* Sets positioning, of nav bar and sets transition speed when opening hamburger menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  margin-right: 5%;
} /* Sets positioning of hamburger icon and adds the pointer cursor when users hover over the icon */

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
} /* Sets colour and sizing of the hamburger menu icon */

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
} /* Sets size, positioning and animation speed for the hamburger menu icon */

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
} /* Sets positioning of the third part of the hamburger menu */
 
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
} /* Sets positioning of the first part of the hamburger menu */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
} /* Prevents small additional hamburger button from appearing on the screen */

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 500px;
} /* Sets the maximum height that the hamburger menu can reach while opened */

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
} /* Prevents middle part of the hamburger menu displaying through the cross while the hamburger menu is open */

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
} /* Sets positioning of one part of the hamburger menu icon create a cross */

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
} /* Sets positioning of one part of the hamburger menu icon create a cross */

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
} /* Sets positioning of the hamburger icon when closed and opened */

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
START OF RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION MOBILE VIEW
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
START OF 104em = 1668px RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION MOBILE VIEW
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

/* 104em = 1668px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1668px) {

  .header .logo {
    font-size: 3.2em;
    margin-left: 5%;
  } /* Sets positioning, removes any text decoration, sets font-size */
  
  .header .menu {
    transition: max-height .3s ease-out;
    margin-right: 5%;
  } /* Sets positioning, of nav bar and sets transition speed when opening hamburger menu icon */
  
  .header .menu-icon {
    padding: 38px 10px;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
  } /* Sets positioning of hamburger icon and adds the pointer cursor when users hover over the icon */
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon {
    width: 22px;
  } /* Sets colour and sizing of the hamburger menu icon */
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    width: 100%;
  } /* Sets size, positioning and animation speed for the hamburger menu icon */
  }
  
  /* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  END OF 104em = 1668px RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION MOBILE VIEW
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

  /* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
START OF 104em = 1668px RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION MOBILE VIEW
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

/* 104em = 1668px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1310px) {

  .header .logo {
    font-size: 3.2em;
    margin-left: 5%;
  } /* Sets positioning, removes any text decoration, sets font-size */
  
  .header .menu {
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
  } /* Sets positioning, of nav bar and sets transition speed when opening hamburger menu icon */

  .header .menu-icon {
    padding: 38px 0px;
    margin-right: 5%;
  } /* Sets positioning of hamburger icon and adds the pointer cursor when users hover over the icon */
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon {
    width: 22px;
  } /* Sets colour and sizing of the hamburger menu icon */
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    width: 100%;
  } /* Sets size, positioning and animation speed for the hamburger menu icon */
  }
  
  /* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  END OF 104em = 1668px RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION MOBILE VIEW
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
START OF 1471em = 1471px RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION MOBILE VIEW
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

/* 92em = 1471px */
@media (min-width: 1310px) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  } /* Sets floating position of the nav links */

  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 25px;
  } /* Sets padding to the nav links */
  
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  } /* Sets positioning of nav links and sets float */
  
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  } /* Stops the hamburger menu icon from appearing when in other views outwith mobile view */
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
END OF 48em = 768px RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION MOBILE VIEW
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
START OF 36em = 577px RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION MOBILE VIEW
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

/* 36em = 577px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 577px) {

.header .logo {
  font-size: 3.2em;
  margin-left:2.5%;
} /* Sets positioning, removes any text decoration, sets font-size */

.header .menu {
  transition: max-height .3s ease-out;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
} /* Sets positioning, of nav bar and sets transition speed when opening hamburger menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  padding: 38px 10px;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
} /* Sets positioning of hamburger icon and adds the pointer cursor when users hover over the icon */

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  width: 22px;
} /* Sets colour and sizing of the hamburger menu icon */

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
} /* Sets size, positioning and animation speed for the hamburger menu icon */
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
END OF 36em = 577px RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION MOBILE VIEW
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
END OF RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION MOBILE VIEW
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
START OF ALERT MESSAGE BOX
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */
.alert-message {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
} /* Adjusts sizing and alignment of alert message underneath the navigation bar */

/* 85em = 1366px*/
@media (max-width: 1669px) {
  .alert-message {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
  } /* Adjusts sizing and alignment of alert message underneath the navigation bar */

  /* 64em = 1023px*/
  @media (max-width: 1023px) {
    .alert-message {
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: 7.5%;
      margin-right: 7.5%;
    } /* Adjusts sizing and alignment of alert message underneath the navigation bar */
  }
}

/* 48em = 768px*/
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .alert-message {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
  } /* Adjusts sizing and alignment of alert message underneath the navigation bar */
}

/* 36em = 577px*/
@media (max-width: 577px) {
  .alert-message {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
  } /* Adjusts sizing and alignment of alert message underneath the navigation bar */
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
END OF ALERT MESSAGE BOX
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
START OF HOME SECTION IMAGE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

.home-section-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.15), rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.35)),
  url("../images/pexels-photo-258109.jpg");
  opacity: .90;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  
  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 650px; 
  
  /* Create the image scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
} /* Sets sizing, positioning and adds scroll effect the main home page image */

/* 85em = 1366px*/
@media (max-width: 1669px) {
  .home-section-image {
    min-height: 625px; 
  } /* Sets sizing, positioning and adds scroll effect the main home page image */
}

/* 64em = 1023px*/
@media (max-width: 1023px) {
  .home-section-image {
    min-height: 625px; 
  } /* Sets sizing, positioning and adds scroll effect the main home page image */
}

/* 48em = 768px*/
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .home-section-image {
    min-height: 625px; 
  } /* Sets sizing, positioning and adds scroll effect the main home page image */
} 


/* 36em = 577px*/
@media (max-width: 577px) {
  .home-section-image {
    min-height: 625px; 
  } /* Sets sizing, positioning and adds scroll effect the main home page image */
}


/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
END OF HOME SECTION IMAGE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>KPM</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home-page.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">    
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- Google Font -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather+Sans:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- Google Font (logo) -->
<script src="javascript/responsive-nav.js?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
<header class="header">
  <a href="" class="logo">KPM</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="middle">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="middle">Memorials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="middle">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="middle">Other Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="middle">Materials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="middle">Designs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="middle">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="middle">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<div class="alert-message">
  <p><strong>Coronavirus (COVID-19) Statement: </strong>To comply with the current restrictions, we regret that we are closed to visitors. However, we are still 
  operating behind closed doors during normal business hours, so please contact us by telephone or email.</p>
</div>
    
    <section id="home" class="home-section">
      <!--<h1 class="home-section-title"><span>PositiveTalkwithAJ</span></h1>-->

      <div class="home-section-image">
      
      </div>

    </section>
<h2 style="margin-left:15%;">This is currently a test template!</h2>

    
<?php
    include 'footer/footer.php';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be faster to fix having a working example somewhere. I would bet it's based on padding/margin.

Comment: Is there anything you would suggest I upload it onto for a working example?

Comment: no, it's your choice, because there are dozens of possibilites (codepen, pastebin, ...). Put it somewhere where you feel happy with - even your own webspace.

Comment: Ideally you would edit your post above to put the code into an runnable snippet.

Comment: It should be available now as a snippet.

Comment: as already mentioned: it's a padding of ".menu" (your UL). Set in your snippet to padding:0 and see, it's gone.

Comment: @NathanBayne if a solution is correct you need to click the checkmark and accept it as the answer.